# set default data for symfony choice field with multiple set to true

Tags: forms, symfony, checkbox, default-value

I am trying to render a choice field with checkboxes and I want, in edit mode, this to have the data the user previously checked meaning a way to set default data. the below code does not work. can someone help please. thank you

```
$days = array("monday" => "monday","tuesday" => "tuesday");
$builder->add('channels', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array(
                'days'  => $days,                
            ),
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
            'required' => true,
            'data' => array("choices" => array("days" => array("monday")))
        ));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
$builder->add(
    'channels',
    'choice',
    array(
        ...
        'data' => array("monday"),
    )
)
```

Comment: try ```'data' => array('monday'=>'Monday','tuesday'=>'Tuesday')```

Comment: it is giving me the same result

Comment: I have realized that it's working I just forgot something in my variables when I tested with an array with multiple elements . CiTNOH is also explaining it

Answer (score 3):

This One worked for me (Symfony 2.3.x):

```
$days = array("monday" => "Monday","tuesday" => "Tuesday","wednesday" => "wednesday","thursday" => "thursday");
    $builder->add('channels', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => array(
            'days'  => $days,                
        ),
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true,
        'required' => true,
        'data' => array("wednesday","thursday","tuesday")
    ));
```

Note: Use the key index to set the Data not the value. "Tuesday" will not work here as "tuesday" does.

Comment: Still works in Symfony v3.3 (when used with regular v3.3 syntax). Tnx.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `choices` key in the data array:

`$builder->add(
    'channels',
    'choice',
    array(
        ...
        'data' => array("monday")
    )
);`

Comment: Your solution is throwing the following exception : "Notice: Array to string conversion in /xxx/xxx/xxx/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/ChoiceList/ChoiceList.php line 457"